# creating a .rwl object

Tags: r, csv

I have some tree data i want to process with the `dplr` package.
My problem is that I only have the data as a Excel file, so I exported the data as .csv which I then got into R with

```
a <- read.csv(file = "")
```

I need to transform this data to `.rwl` to be able to run some `dplr` functions.

My guess is I need to run the `write.rwl()` command - but I don't understand how to set it up properly, although I found the help file [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplR/versions/1.6.4/topics/write.rwl)

I don't get what I should do with the arguments:

1. `rwl.df` => is this my .csv data? Why does it say: "This type of data.frame is produced by `read.rwl`"?
2. `fname` => the name or location of my .csv or the name I want the output to have?
3. Do I need the `read.rwl` command?

Also I do not understand the example given on that page further down.
Could someone explain it to me a bit more simply?

Comment: .rwl is a data format for so called chronologies. If you want to build a chronology from a data.frame (result of `read.csv`), use the functions `detrend` and  `chron` in `dplR`.

Comment: thank you - I will look into that! :-)

Answer (score 1):

in `DplR Package` use the `write.tucson()`function as follow :

`library("dplR")
dat <- read.table ("column.txt", header = T, row.names = 1)
write.tucson (dat, "tucson.txt", prec = 0.01, long.names = TRUE)`

you have all details on how `write.tucson` works with the `?dplR::write.tucson()` command ;)