# R : Column delimited tree-rings dataset into TUCSON file (*.RWL)

Tags: r

Tucson File is a standard format for tree-ring dataset (see : http://www.cybis.se/wiki/index.php?title=Tucson_format) for a precise description.

The aim is to convert Excel files with 1st Column as `YEARS`, and other columns as `MEASUREMENTS` into that RWL format to run DplR package on R.

Some clues are already on ([creating a .rwl object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42118218/gnu-r-creating-a-rwl-object)) but actually, `Chron()` and `Detrend()` functions doen't handle column files as they introduce NAs by coercion.

I've been working many ways to built a "brutal" loop without succeeding, but I'm wondering if a smarter way is possible under R environment ?
Anyway, if somebody here is able to help on a loop I'll take it :)

Thanks a lot !
Alex,

Answer (score 0):

OK, DplR Package have a `write.tucson()`function (o_O)

`library("dplR")`

`dat <- read.table ("column.txt", header = T, row.names = 1)`

`write.tucson (dat, "tucson.txt", prec = 0.01, long.names = TRUE)`